# How does Vala support the C language's __function__ __file__ __line__ macros?

Tags: vala

I need add some log informations with souce file name, function name,

line number etc...

I have check the official docs, but not found...

so, how to do for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually done via [GLib logging](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Message-Logging.html).

For example try this Vala application:

```cs
int main (string[] args) {
    // info () is not shown by default, set G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all in your shell to see them
    info ("Hello World");
    warning ("Hello World");
    //assert_true (false);
    // error () terminates the program
    error ("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all src/glib_logging_test 
** INFO: glib_logging_test.vala:4: Hello World

** (process:10129): WARNING **: glib_logging_test.vala:5: Hello World

** (process:10129): ERROR **: glib_logging_test.vala:9: Hello World
Trace/Breakpoint ausgelöst
```

You can also set `G_DEBUG` in addition to `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG`, see [running GLib applications](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-running.html).

You can install [a custom handler](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Log.set_handler) with `Log.set_handler ()` as well.

There is also `Log.FILE`, `Log.LINE`, `Log.METHOD` for the raw information equivalent to the C macros.

Comment: If intermediary C code is generated (e.g. with `--ccode`), it's important to set the `--debug` flag so that the macros can resolve file, line and method properly.